# How to understand the "program ignoring my input request" from the C++ FAQ?

Tags: c++, iostream

I am trying to understand the item:

[Why is my program ignoring my input request after the first iteration?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#istreams-remember-bad-state)

from the C++ FAQ.

I compiled the test program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        char name[1000];
        int age;
        for (;;) 
        {
                std::cout << "Name: ";
                std::cin  >> name;
                std::cout << "Age: ";
                std::cin  >> age;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

and everything seems to be working fine. Yet, the authors say that there is a problem:

> Because the numerical extractor leaves non-digits behind in the input
>   buffer.

and that the correct source code should be this:

```
int main()
{
        char name[1000];
        int age;
        for (;;) 
        {
                std::cout << "Name: ";
                std::cin  >> name;
                std::cout << "Age: ";
                std::cin  >> age;
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Please, could you explain what is the desired behavior of the program and how can I get the undesired behavior?

EDIT:

The problem was that I did not expect that the program should handle errors, such as entering `10b` when numeric input is expected. Indeed the authors' modification handles such errors, but does not handle errors of the user inputting e.g. `b10`.

Comment: I'm not sure what's unclear here?!

Comment: @LightningRacisinOrbit I edited my question to describe my problem of understanding better.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example if you enter a for the name and then 10b for the age the output of the program is

```
Name: a
Age: 10b
Name: Age:
```

Now the reason we get this is the b from 10b is left in the stream and then the next time `std::cin  >> name;` is called it grabs the b and proceeds to ask for the age.  in the second example `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` will get rid of the letters after the number and the program will behave correctly.

Comment: Ah yes, this is it. I didn't think the program should account for the possibility of the user inputting something like `10b`.

Comment: @DrewDormann Why did you delete your answer? It made the most sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

In your first code, for `age`, if you enter a character instead of a number, then `cin` will leave that in the input stream and the next `cin` will try to read that. So, it will not take input for that.

Let us take a simple run of your code for three iterations of your for loop,

Input and Output

```
Name: ar
Age: a
Name: Age:
Name: Age:
```

As you can see, no more values are asked of the user if you enter a character for `age`. To prevent that, and flush the buffer to get rid of the unwanted characters in the buffer, you use

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

But I personally think it's better to use a `cin.clear();` as well.

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

That will get rid of all the remaining unwanted characters in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
int main()
{
    char name[1000];
    int age;
    char name2[1000];

    std::cout << "Name: ";
    std::cin >> name;
    std::cout << "Age: ";
    std::cin >> age;
    std::cin >> name2;

    std::cout << "Name: \"" << name << "\"" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Age: \"" << age << "\"" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Name2: \"" << name2 << "\"" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you enter in:
`John`
`23 Doe`

name2 is read in as `Doe`.  If you were executing code between reading `age` and `name2`, weird things could happen.  By clearing the buffer between reads, that doesn't happen.